# Mqtt for Arduino (CC 3000)

Tags: arduino, mqtt, texas-instruments

I'm planning to use CC 3000 (Wi-fi) with my Arduino to communicate with cloud. I'm wondering do we have any MQTT client for Arduino by supporting CC 3000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fork of my [Arduino Client for MQTT](http://knolleary.net/arduino-client-for-mqtt/) available that claims support for the CC3000 hardware:

https://github.com/nathanchantrell/pubsubclient

Comment: Any possibility we can get CC3000 support into the original PubSubClient library?

Comment: Did you get it working? Trying it out with no results for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

http://knolleary.net/arduino-client-for-mqtt/  this supports mqtt library and can be used for implimenting the mqtt library. hope this is the one you are asking